# Как увеличить, регистр буквы в массиве не первой а например 2 или 3 буквы

Tags: javascript, массивы, map

Извините за примитивный вопрос, но меня интересует, как в массиве увеличить регистр буквы, например не первой буквы, а например 2 или 3. Вот мой код, я меня значения, в методе `slice(1)` но нечему нормальному это не приводит, вот мой код.

```
s=["soo", "xum", "voo", "soo"];
 x=s.map(function(ro){return ro[0].toUpperCase()+ro.slice(1)})
console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так можно со второй буквы:
Пояснения(`ro[0](вставляем первую букву)+ro[1].toUpperCase()(Тут укзываем какую букву переводить в верхний регистр)+ro.slice(2)(Добавляем окончание с 2 позиции, так как букву с индексом 1 перевели в верхний регистр и добавили)`

```js
    s=["soo", "xum", "voo", "soo"];
x=s.map(function(ro){return ro[0]+ro[1].toUpperCase()+ro.slice(2)});
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Извините за глупый вопрос, я хочу понять зачем мы плюсуем ro[0]+ro[1].t

Comment: @Грустьжизни предвкушая Ваш вопрос добавил описание )))

Comment: Спасибо я поставлю вам галочку благодарности, но она пока не срабатывает)

Comment: @Грустьжизни, Не переживайте ) Главное помочь, всё остальное тлен )

Comment: Если Вы не против могу вам еще обратится? В Node Js понимаете ?  Сейчас ищу примитивный пример соединия ноды и redis

Comment: @Грустьжизни, Конечно. ) Не сказал бы что прям что супер-профессионал, но с нодой работаю ) Вот несколько примеров https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis https://habr.com/ru/post/440546/ https://redislabs.com/lp/node-js-redis/ Всё зависит от того, что именно планируете сделать )

Comment: Меня интересует, а как хешах можно увеличивать буквы, я пытался сделать такой вариант, но он увеличивает все подряд, а как сделать, такой же номер, но с хешами вот что я пытлся сделать s={a:"yes", get zoo(){
  return this.a.toUpperCase();
}, 
set zoo(x){
 return this.a;
}
}
console.log(s.zoo)
 s.a="no";
 console.log(s.zoo)